# How to stop Youtube API saving OAuth token in a file?

Tags: .net, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, youtube.net-api

By a coincidence I found that refresh and access OAuth tokens are stored in roaming folder of a user after successful authorization.

**Is there a way to stop doing it?**

Also I am just curious - how is it Google thinking its a good approach to store refresh token on a disk? (especially not telling the user about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently (after some experimenting) if you don't supply your own data store the API saves it in your Windows roaming folder `\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth`

however if you **provide an "empty" data store this wont happen**.

here is the code:

```
UserCredential credential = null;

var ds = new YoutubeDataStore();

using (var stream = new FileStream("client_id.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload, },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None, 
        ds
    );
}
```

Data store:

```
public class YoutubeDataStore : IDataStore
{
    public Task ClearAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<T>(default(T));
    }

    public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<T>(default(T));
    }

    public Task StoreAsync<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<T>(default(T));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 99.99% certain that Google is **not** storing any tokens anywhere.

The user has authed using an app, so what the app does with those tokens is out of Google's control (unless you are saying that the app was one of Google's). You might want to address the question to the app author.

Comment: thank you for such forceful demonstration of conviction. but it does. Google YouTube data API v3 does..

Comment: ooooooo no it doesn't. An API is just that, an interface. Interfaces do nothing. If a refresh token is being written to disk, that is being done by a piece of code. You need to update your question to describe exactly what code you believe was run that created the Refresh Token. Sadly, without that, your question is meaningless.

Comment: So, to clarify, it is the .net OAuth library which is saving the refresh tokens. The whole point of a refresh token is that it is saved somewhere so it can be retrieved and used to create access tokens. I think your point is that the documentation could do a better job of explaining this behaviour.

Comment: Last time I checked, the L in DLL stood for Library